# Combining line chart data with bar plot together with pgfplotstable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I try to create a combined line chart and bar plot and I found a solution in the question [Combining line chart data with bar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252305/combining-line-chart-data-with-bar-plot)

But I have problems to combine the two charts with data from a table, defined by the pgfplotstable-package.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&, header=true]{
firm  &value&value2
Firm 1&3    &4
Firm 2&7    &8
Firm 3&8    &9
Firm 4&13   &14
Firm 5&16   &17
}\mydata

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xtick=data,
   xticklabels from table={\mydata}{firm},      
   bar width=7mm, y=4mm,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
  ]
\addplot table [ybar, y=value, x expr=\coordindex,] {\mydata};  %Works not
\addplot table [y=value2, x expr=\coordindex] {\mydata}; %Works
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My result:
[image]

The ybar-parameter of my first plot is ignored in my example.

Is there an error in my example or does `\addplot table` not support ybar?

Comment: Surely, you mean `\addplot [ybar] table [y=value, x expr=\coordindex,] {\mydata};` I make the same mistake all the time `;)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ybar` option is a plotting option, not a table parsing option.

It should be passed to `\addplot`, not to `table`

### The code

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&, header=true]{
  firm  &value&value2
  Firm 1&3    &4
  Firm 2&7    &8
  Firm 3&8    &9
  Firm 4&13   &14
  Firm 5&16   &17
}\mydata

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\mydata}{firm},      
        bar width=7mm, y=4mm,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
      ]
      \addplot [ybar] table [y=value, x expr=\coordindex,] {\mydata};  % now works 
      \addplot table [y=value2, x expr=\coordindex] {\mydata}; %Works
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so easy. Thank you.