# How to draw 2 curves in the same tikzpicture having 2 columns information for each curve

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am aiming to establish a tikzpicture that have two curves, the first curve have the following X and Y values and the second curve have the following X and Y values all the values for both the X and Y axes range from 0 to 1. Now I found this example as a starting point but not sure how to modify it since it assume that the X values is the same for both curves and only Y axis differs. Is there a way to achieve my needs?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14}
%enter the data sets as follows.

\begin{filecontents}{thu3.dat}
X Splits    Part1  Part2
1 Split-1     24    36
2 Split-2       24  34
3 Split-3       22  29
4 Split-4       25  31
5 Split-5   1   1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=0,
x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north, below=10mm},
title={\textbf{\textit{Accuracy}}},
    xlabel=Time,
  ylabel=No. of Channels,
  xticklabel style = {rotate=30,anchor=east},
   enlargelimits = false,
  xticklabels from table={thu3.dat}{Splits},xtick=data]
\addplot[orange,thick,mark=square*] table [y=Part1,x=X]{thu3.dat};
\addlegendentry{Part I}
\addplot[green,thick,mark=square*] table [y= Part2,x=X]{thu3.dat};
\addlegendentry{Part II}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparison between part 1 and part 2 on Thursday}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you want, can you try to expand/clarify? Are you after something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401685/how-to-create-a-combined-plot-containing-the-data-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for your comment, I tried to clarify further my question. Please don't hesitate to ask if it was not clear. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to change:

From the `axis` options you want to remove these three things:

```
xticklabel style = {rotate=30,anchor=east},
xticklabels from table={thu3.dat}{Splits},
xtick=data
```

The first one is somewhat pointless here I think, as you only have numbers. The ticklabels aren't so long that rotating is needed. You don't want to read in the ticklabels from some file I think, I'm guessing you just want the numerical value. And the last one will place a tick at every single data point in the first `\addplot`, which is altogether too much.

For the `\addplot`s themselves, you want

```
\addplot[orange,thick,mark=square*] table[col sep=comma] {Curve_one.csv};
\addplot[green,thick,mark=square*] table[col sep=comma] {Curve_two.csv};
```

possibly with other colours/markers, but that is for you to decide. The colour is set by `orange`/`green`, so to use a different colour just replace these by whatever colour you need. To get a thinner line you can just remove `thick`. (Or replace by `thin`, but I believe that is the default.) If you want to change the size of the markers (the squares), use `mark size=1pt`, where you modify `1pt` to whatever you want.

Here I used the two datafiles you posted links to. `pgfplots` by default assumes that columns in datafiles are separated by whitespace, so `col sep=comma` is needed here. I haven't explicitly specified which column is x and which is y, because `pgfplots` will, unless told otherwise, use the first column for the x-values and the second for the y-values. And that is how those `.csv` files are structured.

To get the labels centered on the axes, the simplest solution is perhaps to change `axis lines=middle` to `axis lines=left`. That will also change another thing, giving you ticklabels for zero, on x- and y-axis. But you have in your code already a method for moving the axis labels, in your original code. So an alternative method would be this:

```
axis lines=middle,
x label style={at={(0.5,0)},below=2.5ex},
y label style={at={(0,0.5)},rotate=90,above=5ex},
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14}
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{108,142,191}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  % either use the following three lines
%  axis lines=middle,
%  x label style={at={(0.5,0)},below=2.5ex},
%  y label style={at={(0,0.5)},rotate=90,above=5ex},
  % or use this one line
  axis lines=left,
  ymin=0,
  title={\textbf{\textit{Accuracy}}},
  xlabel=Time,
  ylabel=No. of Channels,
  enlargelimits = false,
  legend pos=south east
]
\addplot[RYB1, mark=square*] table[col sep=comma] {Curve_one.csv};
\addlegendentry{Part I}
\addplot[RYB3, mark=square*] table[col sep=comma] {Curve_two.csv};
\addlegendentry{Part II}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparison between part 1 and part 2 on Thursday}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ineradicable that was really informative, thank you very much.

Comment: excuse me for bothering, I added a few tiny modifications in a figure in the question if it is possible to do. Thank you very much Torbjørn T.

Comment: @User3700 I'll edit soon. But if you look at `\addplot[orange,thick,mark=square] ..`, what do you think you need to change to make it a different colour (than orange) and thin? Do you want to remove the markers?

Comment: @User3700 I'm a bit baffled. You don't want to fill anything, so why do you think you should add `fill=`? Just replace `orange` with `RYB1`.