# Pareto diagram in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I am an latex beginner and I got to prepare an presentation in overleaf, i wanted to reuse an diagram from my document which Phave made in texmaker, sadly it doesn't work.

I want to generate an Pareto diagram, like this.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion how to do it from scratch?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. One good starting point might be the `pgfplots` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots & https://pgfplots.net/ -- I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: Your question is unclear. I understand that you have made a diagram using LaTeX for your **thesis**. Now you want to use the same diagram in a **presentation** (I assume beamer). Is this correct? If yes, then you need IMHO to provide code that demonstrates the problem. BTW, what does `Phave` mean?

Comment: If you have a picture file (PDF, PNG, JPEG) of the diagram then you can easily include this in a presentation and **save a lot of time**.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but **a start**! See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252305) for a related question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=\# of Errors,
    xlabel= Error Type,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ybar,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    symbolic x coords={3,1,5,4,6,2},
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(3,50) (1,30) (5,10) (4,5) (6,3) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=\# of Errors,
    xlabel= Error Type,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
    %ybar,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    xtick=data,
    %nodes near coords,
    symbolic x coords={3,1,5,4,6,2},
]
\addplot[ybar, nodes near coords] 
    coordinates {(3,50) (1,30) (5,10) (4,5) (6,3) (2,2)};
    %
\addplot[draw, mark=*] 
    coordinates {(3,50) (1,80) (5,90) (4,95) (6,98) (2,100)};   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark:** I would recommend using a diagram with [two y-axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198997) (see also the [`pgfplots` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) Chapter "4.9.11 Two Ordinates (y-axis) or Multiple Axes"), one for the **# of errors** and one of the **percentage**. In your example, you conveniently choose the **total # of errors** to be 100 (%).

Comment: Could it be possible to use `foreach` and so to calculate the cumulative values?

Comment: @projetmbc I am not skilled enough to answer that but I am pretty sure that someone can do it :)